Alternating button presses with a single input
I'm trying to set it up where I click the rmb and it simulates pressing key 1, then when I press it again it presses 2.
I achieved being able to change the rmb to any other keystroke but when I tried setting that up with a var to alternate between 0 and 1 (a boolean really) and trying to read said var with an if statement to decide whether 1 or 2 should be pressed I'm just getting all sorts of errors.

Post the (relevant) code that produces the problem and explain how you weren't able to solve it. Without seing what you tried, it's impossible to know what's happening.
